# How do I convert the result of a LINQ query to a specific object?

Tags: c#

```
Items = (from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
         where myRow.Field<string>("RelatedContactName") == groupName
         select myRow)
```

Items the property of an object.

```
public class Item
{
     public List<Item> Items
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
}
```

Comment: If your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243261/how-do-i-do-a-select-where-on-a-data-table-and-convert-the-results-to-a-complex) gets downvoted, please don't just repost it.

Comment: why is my question being down voted? nobody's been able to answer it yet.

Comment: SLaks gave the correct answer, but you don't seem to understand enough about what you're trying to do to be able to use it.  Questions which show little research or understanding generally get downvoted.

Comment: What makes you think I did little research? if this problem was so easy, it would have been answered by now. Slaks answer, though a good beginning, does not help me here.

Comment: The question hasn't been answered *because* it shows little knowledge or understanding.  SLaks answer is correct and complete, they just haven't actually written the code for you.  Did you write the code you posted in the last question?  That code already used everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object in the `select` clause:

```
select new Item { ... }
```

Comment: can you complete the code? im not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You need to create properties in your class and set them.

Answer (score -1):

```
Items = (from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
     where myRow.Field<string>("RelatedContactName") == groupName
     select myRow).ToList();
```